# Redux toolkit: call function after updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the logic. The user clicks on the button, then the answer changes and is compared with the correct answer.

The problem is that after dispatching, I have a previous version of the state when I try to compare.

What I'm trying to do:

Check.jsx:

```
const Check = () => {
  const {answer, userAnswer} = useSelector(state => state.check);
  const currentAnswer = 'current'

  // here is the main problem, the userAnswer is in the previous state
  const check = () => {
    if(answer === userAnswer){
     // some other stuff
    }
  }
 
  return(
    <div>
     //something else 
     <Button userAnswer={currentAnswer} check={check} />
   </div>
  )
}
```

Button.jsx:

```
const Button = (userAnswer, check) => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return(
    <button onClick={() => {
      dispatch(updateAnswer(userAnswer)).then(() => check())
    }}>
      Check answer
    </button>
  )
}
```

checkSlice.js:

```
export const updateAnswer = createAsyncThunk('surplus/getAllUsers', async (word: string) => {
    return word;
});

const initialState = {
  userAnswer: '',
  answer: 'some string'
}

const checkSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'check',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder.addCase(updateAnswer.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.userAnswer = action.payload;
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do comparison in reducers like

```
export const updateAnswer = createAsyncThunk('surplus/getAllUsers', async (word: string) => {
    return word;
});

const initialState = {
  userAnswer: '',
  check: false
  answer: 'some string'
}

const checkSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'check',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder.addCase(updateAnswer.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            if(state.userAnswer === action.payload){
               state.check = true;
               state.userAnswer = action.payload;
              } else {
               state.check = false;
              }
        });
    },
});
```

You can get **check** variable from redux and then perform action using useEffect on check like

```
useEffect(()=>{
// some other stuff
},[check]) // check from redux
```